# Move Google Sheet with a script to Excel

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, microsoft-excel

I have a Google Sheet that I would like to access and modify also when I'm offline. The problem is that I have a script attached to it so I can't use the "make available offline" option; the script doesn't work then.

So I've been thinking about converting my Google Sheet to an Excel sheet. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do this, but I couldn't find any involving scripts. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets use Google Apps Script while Excel use VBA. None of them have a built-in way to covert a script into a macro and vice versa.

By the other hand both apps have some non-standard spreadsheet features and  that could make very hard to create a tool that makes the conversion automatically as it could imply to rethink the spreadsheet design.